# I am not able to run the D3 code on my local computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have this code https://gist.github.com/kerryrodden/766f8f6d31f645c39f488a0befa1e3c8

when I copy paste this code on my notepad and save the files,it shows an error.
It works fine on JSFiddle, i am not able to run on my local computer.

This is the working code: https://vizhub.com/mhalasa/6a0824c5aeda49adb6bf59b7b2d835ba

but i am not able to do the same on local computer.

This is the error i am getting:
[image: Error while running the code]

Comment: I saved the files in notepad with the appropriate names and then opened the index.html.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Prerna/Desktop/Sunburst/visit-sequences.csv' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, 
This is the error i am getting

Comment: I did add the extension for CORS disabling, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to reach an outside javascript resource running your code from a `file://` protocol, for security reasons.

You should get a [local server](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) running, and reach your html from there.

Comment: Also, this might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local